# A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type in asp.net mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I tried to search but cannot solve my problem.

This is my controller :

```
    public JsonResult Index()
    {
        return this.Json(TempData["displayList"], JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    public JsonResult AddToCart(string id)
    {
        QuotationModels objQuote = new QuotationModels();

        List<QuotationModels> listQuote = objQuote.GetObjectInSession;

        int itemID = Int32.Parse(id);

        int index = -1;
        if(listQuote != null)
           index = listQuote.FindIndex(p => p.ItemdID== itemID);

        if (index >= 0)
        {
            listQuote[index].ProductQty++;
            objQuote.AddToSession(listQuote);
        }
        else
        {
            int _id = Convert.ToInt16(id);
            var _product = DataContext.DataContext.Items.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ID == _id);

            QuotationModels quote = new QuotationModels();
            quote.ItemdID = _product.ID;
            quote.ItemNote = _product.Notes;
            quote.Phone = "";
            quote.PictureName = _product.PictureName;
            quote.ProductName = _product.Name;
            quote.ProductPrice = (decimal)_product.Price;
            quote.ProductQty = 1;
            quote.ShoppingCartId = "";
            quote.Total = 0;
            quote.Email = "";
            quote.CustomerID = 0;
            quote.CusName = "";
            quote.Company = "";
            quote.Address = "";
            objQuote.AddToSession(quote);

        }

        int itemInSession = objQuote.GetObjectInSession.Sum(s => s.ProductQty);
        TempData["displayList"] = objQuote.GetObjectInSession;

        return Json(new
        {
           ja = itemInSession
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

[image: This is the sample data in my TempData]

But when I browse the Index() view, It was an error `A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type`.

Can any one give me the solution please. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to serialize, but here is a clue about what you have to do !

The problem of the circular reference means that you have for exemple a Quote, which contains a reference to a Product. And that that Product itsel has a reference to the parent Quote.

You can't serialize that simply in JSON, cause it would do something like this:

```
Quote :
 - some attributes..
 - Product
   - some attributes
   - Quote 
     - some attributes...
     - Product... and so on !
```

But now, if you have the parent Quote, is it really interesting for you to have the relationship on the child entity ? Maybe in your server-side model, but it's kind of redundant and not necessary for the client.

What you could do in that case is create other classes which don't contain what is not necessary and could result in circular reference.

You'll have for example a SimpleQuote, which is like a Quote, but instead of having a Product property, it will have a SimpleProduct property.

Original classes :

```
public class Quote{
    public int Id;
    public Product Product;
    public double Amount;
}

public class Product{
    public int Id;
    public Quote Quote;
    public string Name;
}
```

Simple classes for serialization :

```
public class SimpleQuote{
    public int Id;
    public SimpleProduct Product;
    public double Amount;
}

public class SimpleProduct{
    public int Id;
    public int QuoteId;
    public string Name;

}
```

Now you can create extensions methods like :

```
public static void ToSimpleQuote(this Quote quote){
    return new SimpleQuote(){ 
        Id = quote.Id,
        Amount = quote.Amount,
        Product = quote.Product.ToSimpleProduct()
    };
}

public static void ToSimpleProduct(this Product product){
    return new SimpleProduct(){
        Id = product.Id,
        Name = product.Name,
        QuoteId = product.Quote.QuoteID
    };
}
```

So if you had something like :

```
public ActionResult Index(){
    ....
    return Json(myQuote, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

you can now do this instead :

```
public ActionResult Index(){
    ....
    return Json(myQuote.ToSimpleQuote(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't return `this`.  Instead use:

```
 public JsonResult Index()
    {
        return Json(TempData["displayList"], JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Can you show the object graph of what is in `TempData["displayList"]`?

You might have a looping hierarchy.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean `Object Graph` in here? But actually, I'm not yet loop it in my view.

Comment: @socheata what do you put into TempData["displayList"]?  can you show the code and any nested objects within it please.  The object that has Phone, PictureName, etc

Comment: @socheata have you tried removing the this.  TempData also uses session, would it not be clearer if you read your objQuote.GetObjectInSession direct from session again like in your AddCart (obviously not updating anything like in AddCart)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the attributes XMLIgnore for strict XML Serializing or NonSerialized for broader targets.

Simply mark the properties or fields that are circular with either of these attributes and it should ignore them.

Works well in Entity Framework scenarios with virtual members properties that are indeed circular references.